# Flutter web push notification with firebase

Tags: flutter, web, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I configured Flutter to receive push notifications,but I couldn't find a way for the web platform.
All the articles and tutorials are a bit old and I think they are useless.

I used the flutterfire command to configure Firebase, which works perfectly for Android.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add firebase_core and firebase_messaging to your pubspec.yaml

In your main() function add the init Firebase

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxx"));
```

After initializing Firebase you have to initialize Firebase messaging and ask for Notifications in the Browser, which you do like this

```
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.getNotificationSettings();
```

Add this in a javascript file

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('Received background message ', payload);

    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
      };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Add this to your index.html file

```
<script>
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
      });
  }
</script>
```

Then you are basically good to go, that is all you have to do. Then go to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/your-project-id/messaging and add your flutter web app to it, and send a test notification to your application by getting the token from your application by using await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();